# Bootstrap - Why is my navbar background color being overwritten even when I specify it?

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, laravel

Why does my navbar both side have a white background color?

I used the developer tool to try and help me and the part that change it white was the navbar default. I try to change the css inside the developer tool using this and it work.

This is the part that I changed inside the developer tool:

```
.navbar-default {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

I also tried to change in the `app.css` and change the `navbar-default` to blue but the problem is still occurring, and when I check inside the developer tool, the color code is white instead of the blue that I had just changed. But it works if I change it inside the developer tool.

I tried following this question, but it doesn't work as well:

[Background color in navbar laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47091076/background-color-in-navbar-laravel).

My page consists of an HTML table, and I have used `@extends` to put the navbar inside this page. When I try doing it for other pages, the navbar works.

`htmlTable.blade.php`:

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('title', 'Summary')
    @section('content')
        <div class="container" style="background-color:#ADD8E8"> 
            //content of my html table
        </div>   
    @endsection
```

`app.blade.php` (navbar):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ app()->getLocale() }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- CSRF Token -->
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

   <title>@yield('title')</title>

    <!-- Styles -->
    <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{{ asset('css/title.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">


                    <!-- Collapsed Hamburger -->
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#app-navbar-collapse" aria-expanded="false">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    @include('layouts.testSidebar')

                    <!-- Branding Image -->
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ url('/') }}" style="color: white">
                        @yield('title')
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="app-navbar-collapse">
                    <!-- Left Side Of Navbar -->
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        &nbsp;
                    </ul>
                    <!-- Right Side Of Navbar -->
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <!-- Authentication Links -->
                        @guest
                            <li><a href="{{ route('login') }}">Login</a></li>
                            <li><a href="{{ route('register') }}">Register</a></li>
                        @else
                            <li class="dropdown">
                                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" style="background-color:blue">
                                    <b style="color: white">{{ Auth::user()->name }}</b> <span class="caret"></span>
                                </a>

                                <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="background-color: blue">
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="{{ route('logout') }}"
                                            onclick="event.preventDefault();
                                                     document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();" style="background-color: blue">
                                            <b style="color: white">Logout</b>
                                        </a>

                                        <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
                                            {{ csrf_field() }}
                                        </form>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        @endguest
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>

        @yield('content')
    </div>

    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

`test.css` (this is the CSS that I used):

```
body{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    font-family:"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial;
}

#sidebar{
    background:blue;
    width:200px;
    height:100%;
    display:block;
    position:fixed;
    left:-200px;
    top:0px;
    transition:left 0.3s linear;
}

#sidebar.visible{
    left:0px;
    transition:left 0.3s linear;
}

ul{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}

ul li{
    list-style:none;
}

ul li a{
    background:#0000FF ;
    color:white;
    border-bottom:1px solid #111;
    display:block;
    width:180px;
    padding:10px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#sidebar-btn{
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width:20px;
    height:15px;
    cursor:pointer;
    margin:20px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    right:-60px;
}

#sidebar-btn span{
    height:1px;
    background:white;
    margin-bottom:5px;
    display:block;
}

#sidebar-btn span:nth-child(2){
    width:75%;
}

#sidebar-btn span:nth-child(3){
    width:50%;
}

#navbar-toggle collapsed{
    background:#0000FF ;

}

.navbar {background:#0000FF ;}

 nav.sidebar .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>li>a:hover, nav.sidebar .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>li>a:focus {
    color: white;
    background-color: transparent;
}
.dropdown-menu {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 180px;
    min-width: 180px;
}
```

This is what happens:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change this:

```
<div id="app">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
```

to:

```
<div id="app">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
```

The container-fluid class is the one you want

Comment: After playing it around, I finally realized that I also need to use the style function to make the whole navbar change color since just by doing container-fluid, it only makes the right side of navbar have the color for some reason